# Chrome Extension: Content Security Policy Error

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am working on Chrome extension which opens a new window. That window contains my `page.html` where there are some scripts and that's the problem because in the console I can see the error... and now.

When I don't add any additional stuff to my `manifest.json` or `page.html` I get this error:

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-t+n/+H6ALc8VWtFbu1Zd7/MPwtSjSk8PIrfccO7FJrg='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.`,

If I add

```
 "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' chrome-extension://capfbnhhhkfclmggnafjgkolommmmoch; object-src 'self';"
```

to my `manifest.json`, I get

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension://capfbnhhhkfclmggnafjgkolommmmoch". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-t+n/+H6ALc8VWtFbu1Zd7/MPwtSjSk8PIrfccO7FJrg='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

When I added some `meta` tag into my `page.html` there was a same or similar error.

And my question is: How can I fix it? Because I think that `"script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:"` is some kind of template so I have to add some data thereafter `:`s... But I really don't know which. I saw [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src) something about it but I don't have clue what should I do with it or where I should write it. So please help me, I would be so happy if I fixed that error.

Code where window opens:

```
$.get(chrome.extension.getURL('/page.html'), function(data) {
    var myWindow;
    myWindow = window.open("", "TopSerialy.sk Vyhľadávač","width=386,height=290");
    myWindow.moveTo((screen.width/2)-(386/2), ((screen.height-93)/2)-(290/2));
    myWindow.document.write(data);
});
```

`page.html` contains only simple script to close window when butten is pressed, declared by `<script>functions, etc...</script>` tag in HTML, not `<script scr="some_url/script.js"></script>`!

Comment: Simply use a separate js file as explained in [onClick within Chrome Extension not working](//stackoverflow.com/a/25721457)

Comment: wohooo! thanks! I was wondering about something like that but with my unluck it wouldnt work... but maybe yes :D thank you !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This does not work, because Chrome [forbids any kind of inline code](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution) in extensions via Content Security Policy.

What you can do is:

1. Put all inline code into some file `(popup.js)`.
2. Add to your code `<script src="popup.js"></script>`